# How to use radio type for ng-repeat and what should be the ng-model?

Tags: html, angularjs, radio-button

I have 10 questions for some survey, each has to be answered either yes or no.
I want to use radio-option, and I want to get these questions in ng-repeat.
How can I use this? **What should be the ng-model for each question?**

```
<form>
 <div ng-init="watch()">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
   <label>{{question.id}}{{question .question}}</label>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="?" value="No">No
   <input type="radio" ng-model="?" value="Yes">Yes
    {{msg}}
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

in script

```
$scope.$watch('?',function() {  // ? is ng-model 
 if ($scope.? == "No") {
    $scope.msg = "no";
 } else {
    $scope.msg = "yes";     
 }
});
```

i use ng-model as {{question.id}}, but it's not working
please help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

ng-model contains your answer.
so if you have answer variable in question class you can use that.

```
<form>
 <div>
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
   <label>{{question.id}}{{question .question}}</label>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="question.answer" value="no">No
   <input type="radio" ng-model="question.answer" value="yes">Yes
    {{question.answer}}
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

i don't know i was correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
  <div>
    <div *ngFor=" let question of question">
      <label>{{question.id}}{{question.q1}}</label>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="?" value="No">No <input type="radio" ng-model="?" value="Yes">Yes {{msg}}
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Using this code works for me.

Comment: Can you please explain your code and not just paste it?